# Would a Counterexample to Navier-Stokes Problem be Sufficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Given the problem statement for the Navier-Stokes Existence & Smoothness problem from the Clay Institute website, wouldn't one need to show only one counterexample to the conjecture of global existence and smoothness of unique solutions to the Navier-Stokes equations for incompressible viscous flow in 3-Dimensions to win the million dollars (and solve the problem)? (i.e. find two solutions given the same initial data)

Comment: Yes. Good luck with that.

Comment: @SimonS, I came here to write precisely that :D